# ASP.Net Programming Validation ,Combo box inside repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a ASP website in which I have a repeater,  which has a combo box  and textbox.I need to have a text box value converted to uppercase when i select 
particular value from combo box, but not for all values from combo box .I have tried onChange event and onKeypress Event also in javascript,but could not able 
to breakthrough.

```
function changecase(combobOxClientId,textboxClientId)
{
var combo=$find(combobOxClientId);
if(combo.get_value()=='Textvalue')
{
var textbox=$find(textboxClientId).value;

some code here........   `}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to it like this.

```
  function changecase(combobOxClientId, textboxClientId) {
    if ($("#" + combobOxClientId).val() == 'Textvalue') {
      var txtval = $("#" + textboxClientId).val();
      $("#" + textboxClientId).val(txtval.toUpperCase());
    }
  }
```

Assumption : `combobOxClientId, textboxClientId` are actual `ID` of elements existing in page.

Comment: we want to change the text to uppercase when user is typing.There is no value in text box initially

Comment: @MohammadJaved , that depends where you're using this js function(`changecase`), you can put this `onchange` event or `onkeyup` event, but if you want to make it happen on exit of textbox, then use `onblur`.